# $\lambda$ calculus how encode A $\leftrightarrow$ B

Tags: logic, computability, lambda-calculus

I am spending days figuring out how can i show A $\leftrightarrow$ B such that A=B=True or A=B=False as $\lambda$ calculus

I know that we can show :

True ≡ λxy.x

False ≡  λxy.y

and ≡ λpq. p q false

or ≡ λpq. p true q

not ≡ λpq. p false true

are these information enough to solve this problem ?

Please help i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$[A \iff B] \equiv [(A \land B) \lor \neg (A \lor B)]$$

where:

- $\iff$ denotes "iff"
- $\land$ denotes "and"
- $\neg$ denotes "not"
- $\lor$ denotes "or"

---

In conclusion:

`p⟺q := λpq. or (and p q) (not (or p q))`

Expanded:

`p⟺q := λpq. (p q (λxy. y)) (λxy. x) ((p (λxy. x) q) (λxy. y) (λxy. x))`

---

However, there is a shorter equivalent:

`p⟺q := λpq. p q (not q)`

Fully expanded:

`p⟺q := λpq. p q (q (λxy. y) (λxy. x))`

Comment: Thank you Kenny. but problem is i don't know how can i write the whole statement as lambda calculus.  i can write it part by part (for example A $\land$ B), but don't know how should i write it as whole statement.